# How to hide uibutton if its title text is empty or unassigned?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uibutton

The code and question represents an Xcode project in Swift. I have a a group of buttons that display options according to which text is presented on a label.

The label text is derived from the keys of a dictionary and the button texts are derived from the values of that same dictionary. The dictionary type is `[String: [String]`. The keys and values are both placed in arrays. I currently display the correct data but some values differ in length than others.

For example one key has 3 values and another key has 5. I want to hide the buttons if there is not text to send to it. So if a key is presented in a label and has 3 values I only want to display 3 buttons and so. What would be the best way to achieve this functionality? Here is my code that is not achieving want I want to accomplish:

```
func startSurvey() {

    if surveyQuestions.isEmpty {
        surveyQuestions = Array(SampleSurvey().surveyquestions.keys)
        print(surveyQuestions)
    }

    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(surveyQuestions.count)))
    questionTitle.text = surveyQuestions[rand]

    var choices = SampleSurvey().surveyquestions[surveyQuestions[rand]]!
    print(choices)
    print(choices.count)
    surveyQuestions.remove(at: rand)

    var button = UIButton()
    var x = 0
 // var choicePool = choices.count

    if choices.count == 2 {
        for index in 1...2 {
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
            button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
            x += 1
            if button.titleLabel?.text.isEmpty == true {
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }

    else if choices.count == 4 {
    for index in 1...4 {
        button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
        button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
        x += 1

        if button.titleLabel?.text.isEmpty == true {
            button.isHidden = true
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the simulator, as you can see this particular key has only 2 values so there are 3 blank buttons, I want to hide the buttons that are blank:

[image: screenshot of simulator]

UPDATE: The following code has granted me the functionality I was aiming for:

```
      var button = UIButton()
      var x = 0
      let buttonTags = [0,1,2,3,4]
      if choices.count == 2 {
        for idx in buttonTags {
            button = surveyChoices[idx]
            if idx < choices.count {
            button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
            x += 1
            } else {
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use string.isEmpty for checking.

Comment: Tried string.isEmpty yet blank buttons are still appearing

Comment: are you sure you are adding the buttons with the correct tags ?

Comment: This could be improved a lot, if you use a stackview, your survey questions should define the possible repsonses and then dynamically create a UIControl for each, be it a button or switch, slider etc..

Comment: Yes tags are 1,2,3,4,5 I've checked and doubled checked. @SeanLintern88 the buttons are within a stackview

Answer (score 1):

If the `text` in the button's `titleLabel` is `nil`, then your condition will become false.
Try to revise your code like this:

```swift
for index in 1...4 {
    button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
    button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
    x += 1

    if (button.titleLabel?.text ?? "").isEmpty == true {
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

This will check if the `text` is `nil` then it will return a `""` which is empty.

Comment: Still not working as well. Buttons still appear blank

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
**SWIFT 4**

`button.isHidden = button.titleLabel?.text == nil || button.titleLabel?.text == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add the buttons dynamically, one for each choice in the survey. You could easily do this using any of `UITableView`, `UICollectionView` or `UIStackView` by adding a row/cell that contains a button (tableView or collectionView) or just by adding a button to a vertical stack view.

For your specific code, your only iterating over the number of choices, So in the example below (from your code) you are only working on two buttons and not touching the others

```
if choices.count == 2 {
    for index in 1...2 {
        button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
        button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
        x += 1
        if button.titleLabel?.text.isEmpty == true {
            button.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

`for index in 1...2`... your not doing anything with the other 3.

You should loop through all buttons and **if** there is a choice for it, set the title, otherwise hide the button

Here is a working example in a Playground:

```
let question = ["are you expecting a child": ["yes", "no"]]
let choices = question["are you expecting a child"]!

let buttonTags = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let buttons = [
    UIButton(),
    UIButton(),
    UIButton(),
    UIButton(),
    UIButton()
]

for idx in buttonTags {
    let button = buttons[idx]
    if idx < choices.count {
        button.setTitle(choices[idx], for: .normal)
    } else {
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}

buttons.map {
    print($0.titleLabel?.text)
    print($0.isHidden)
}
```

**OUPUT**

```
Optional("yes")
false
Optional("no")
false
nil
true
nil
true
nil
true
```